# scikit learn svm always gives constant line fit

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I am unable to understand why I am getting same constant line fit even after varying parameters significantly

My code -

```
data_set = np.reshape([d[len(d)-2] for d in data_vector], (len(data_vector), 1)); 

plt.scatter(data_set, Y[:,0], c='k', label='data');
#train the regression model

C_Array = [1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e4, 1e-4];
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'];
ind = 0;
for c in C_Array:
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel="rbf", C=c, gamma=0.001);
    plt.hold('on');    
    y1_predictor = svr_rbf.fit(data_set, Y[:, 0]);
    y2_predictor = svr_rbf.fit(data_set, Y[:, 1]);

    sys.stdout.write(".");
    my_prediction = y1_predictor.predict(data_set)
    plt.plot(data_set, my_prediction, c=colors[ind], label='RBF model')
    ind = ind + 1;
plt.show();
```

Output - [image]

Answer (score 4):

Scale your data before fitting SVR (currently you have values 200-1000 on X axis and -400 - 400 on Y axis), otherwise you might need really huge values of gamma/C in order to get any reasonable results. And this is exactly what is happening, for such huge values 1e4 is way to small to make SVR learn anything. Furthermore, for such scale it is easily to under-/overflow floats. You are working with RBF kernel which is of form exp(-g|x-y|^2), thus if |x-y| is ~400 (which is a case in your data), then you get exp(-0.001 * 160000) which numerically is zero.